# Pandas Column Calculations in PivotTable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas. I created this pivot table, but I need to figure out how to apply a function within each day on the 'is_match' values only. See img below for head of data.

What I need is the % of values (reward_count) which is true for each day, per app (rows).

i.e. for date = '2015-10-22', total(true+false) = 59,101. % true would be 1,080/59,101 = 0.018%. For each date, I would just want to see this % true value in place of true/false counts.

original data:

```
date    app_name    is_match    rewards_count
10/22/15    NFL HUDDLE 2016 FALSE   45816
10/22/15    NFL HUDDLE 2016 TRUE    1080
10/22/15    NFL HUDDLE 2016 FALSE   8
10/22/15    NFL HUDDLE 2016 FALSE   128239
10/23/15    NFL HUDDLE 2016 TRUE    908
10/23/15    NFL HUDDLE 2016 FALSE   18
10/24/15    NFL HUDDLE 2016 TRUE    638
```

The data frame:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['app_name'], 
                       columns=['date','is_match'],
                       values = 'rewards_count')
```

[image: sample data]

Thank you so much for your help. I have spend half the day looking through Pandas documentation but do not know what I'm looking for / what to reference.

Comment: could post few records of original data frame before applying pivot.?

Comment: Reason is pivot you created made Date as columns so it makes harder to calculate the average for each date. You can deal that with group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a multi index can help:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(apps, index=['app_name', 'date'], 
                       columns=['is_match'],
                       values = 'rewards_count',
                       aggfunc=np.sum,
                       margins=True)
```

I sum up all counts with `aggfunc=np.sum` and calculate the
sum of `True` and `False` with `margins=True`.
These sums end up in `All`:

```
is_match                   False  True     All
app_name        date                          
NFL HUDDLE 2016 10/22/15  174063  1080  175143
                10/23/15      18   908     926
                10/24/15   79322   638   79960
All                       253403  2626  256029
```

I add two new columns that hold the percentages:

```
table['percent_false']  = table[False] / table.All * 100
table['percent_true']  = table[True] / table.All * 100
```

The results looks like this:

```
is_match                   False  True     All  percent_false  percent_true
app_name        date                                                       
NFL HUDDLE 2016 10/22/15  174063  1080  175143      99.383361      0.616639
                10/23/15      18   908     926       1.943844     98.056156
                10/24/15   79322   638   79960      99.202101      0.797899
All                       253403  2626  256029      98.974335      1.025665
```

There is a lot of extra stuff in the table. Selecting only what you want:

```
percent_true = table.ix[:-1, ['percent_true']]
```

gives:

```
is_match                  percent_true
app_name        date                  
NFL HUDDLE 2016 10/22/15      0.616639
                10/23/15     98.056156
                10/24/15      0.797899
```

If you want the mean of the counts, as you did in your approach,
don't use `aggfunc=np.sum`. You also need to sum up by hand:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(apps, index=['app_name', 'date'], 
                       columns=['is_match'],
                       values = 'rewards_count')
table['total'] = table[False] + table[True]
table['percent_false']  = table[False] / table.total * 100
table['percent_true']  = table[True] / table.total * 100
```

Now the result looks like this:

```
is_match                  False  True  total  percent_false  percent_true
app_name        date                                                     
NFL HUDDLE 2016 10/22/15  58021  1080  59101      98.172620      1.827380
                10/23/15     18   908    926       1.943844     98.056156
                10/24/15  79322   638  79960      99.202101      0.797899
```

Again, select only the relevant parts:

```
percent_true = table[['percent_true']]
```

gives:

```
is_match                  percent_true
app_name        date                  
NFL HUDDLE 2016 10/22/15      1.827380
                10/23/15     98.056156
                10/24/15      0.797899
```